# Dio.Post: Mulitple API requests with different urls

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

I have a Future which is called when user trys to login:

```
Future<String> login(String phone, String password) async {

    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('all');
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((fmctoken) => print(fmctoken));

    Response response = await _dio.post(loginUrl, data: {
      "login": phone,
      "password": password,
    });
    return response.data["objectId"];

  }
```

In this Future i also get the fmc_device_token, which I want to upload to other rest_api_url. The problem is, that i need this:   `return response.data["objectId"];`  the objectId to upload the data.

How can I make, that if this Future is called and the objectId received, the value of the fmctoken_device will upload (post) on other url.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your other function where you need `response.data["objectId"];` to upload data
you can call the `login` function and await for its response, then do your updates

```
Future<dynamic> myotherFunction(String phone, String password)async{
var response= await login(phone,password);
//heere  you have your `objectId`
print(response);
}
```